# Basic shell with Python. How to change directory?

Tags: python, windows, shell

Server-side code, which handles the client's sent data.

```
#receiving data
data = client.recv(1024)
# if it's quit, then break out and close socket
if data.decode("UTF-8") == "quit": break
# do shell command
proc = subprocess.Popen(data.decode("UTF-8"), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, \
       stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
# read output
stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
valid = "done"
if stdout_value.decode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors="ignore") == "":
    client.send(valid.encode("utf-8")) # for commands like "C:", which print nothing
# send output
client.send(stdout_value)
```

Client-side code, which sends data (commands) and prints the results

```
reply = input()
client.send(reply.encode("UTF-8"))

receive = client.recv(4096)
print(receive.decode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors="ignore")
```

When I try to use a command such as "cd ..", it doesn't succeed because as far as I know, it changes directory to the child process. Is there any way to change the parent's directory, using the client?

Comment: You can change the working directory with os.chdir(path)

Comment: You should be aware that some shell commands, like `cd` are built-in, but most are external programs with no connection to the shell.  The external commands can be run using `subprocess`, the built-ins cannot.  So if you are writing a shell, decide which are built-in.  To find out existing ones in bash, use, for example, `type cd`, `type kill`, etc.  You probably want a dictionary where the keys are the names of built-ins, values are the functions for each built-in.

Comment: Yeah. I really liked the idea of "custom commands", as Luciano suggested. Based on my needs, I will create them if I can't have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right. "cd" will change the child process dir.

But, you can analyse the command before execute and apply some special behavior.

Beware, ugly code detected.

```
from os import chdir
...
if data.startswith('cd '):
    chdir(data[3:])  # Don't execute with Popen
else:
    proc = .....
```

Comment: Since this is Windows and `data` is UTF-8 encoded, it should be decoded to `unicode` first to use the filesystem's wide-character API. Otherwise it's limited to ASCII.